# Installed NPM Package is Missing TypeScript Compiled JS Files and Declaration Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

I've published a TypeScript library onto NPM. On GitHub the `dist` ([Link to Repository Folder](https://github.com/Elitezen/easy-trivia/tree/main/dist/src)) directory contains all the compiled JavaScript and d.ts files. However when running `npm i <my_package>` the result is a module with a `dist` folder only containing an `index.js`, the `src` folder is still present with the TypeScript files. The `dist/src` folder along with it's JavaScript and d.ts files are not found on the installed package consequently my module is not recognized or typed in Vanilla JavaScript projects.

Library tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/",
    "dist/"
  ]
}
```

Library package.json

```json
{
  "name": "easy-trivia",
  "version": "2.0.3",
  "description": "A wrapper for the Open Trivia Database API. Built with TypeScript, works with VanillaJS.",
  "keywords": [
    "trivia",
    "games",
    "fun",
    "api",
    "easy",
    "typescript",
    "small",
    "quiz",
    "opentriviadatabase",
    "opentdb",
    "opentriviadb"
  ],
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prettier": "npm run build && prettier -w src/",
    "prepublish": "npm run prep",
    "exec": "npm run build && node .",
    "test": "npm run build && npx jest",
    "prep": "npm run build && npm run test && npm run prettier"
  },
  "files": [
    "src",
    "typings"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Elitezen/easy-trivia.git"
  },
  "author": "Elitezen",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Elitezen/easy-trivia/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Elitezen/easy-trivia#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0",
    "npm": ">=7.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish the types, you will need to explicitly include the `dist` directory in the `files` field of your `package.json`. Merely specifying the file in `types` won't actually include it. For `main` this is different, as it will automatically include the specified file. According to the [npm package.json docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#files):

> Certain files are always included, regardless of settings:
>
> - package.json
> - README
> - LICENSE / LICENCE
> - The file in the "main" field

To easily verify which files are included, `npm pack --dry-run` is handy.

Comment: I've added `files: ["dist/"]` to **tsconfig.json** to no avail.

Comment: You'll need to add it to the `package.json`: `"files": ["src", "typings"]` ~> `"files": ["dist", "src", "typings"]`. Let me add this to the answer.

Comment: Ah I see, npm pack is now showing the files being packed as intended. Thank you!